# clflush not flushing the instruction cache

Tags: c++, assembly, x86, cpu-cache

Consider the following code segment:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#define ARRAYSIZE(arr) (sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]))


inline void
clflush(volatile void *p)
{
    asm volatile ("clflush (%0)" :: "r"(p));
}

inline uint64_t
rdtsc()
{
    unsigned long a, d;
    asm volatile ("cpuid; rdtsc" : "=a" (a), "=d" (d) : : "ebx", "ecx");
    return a | ((uint64_t)d << 32);
}

inline int func() { return 5;}

inline void test()
{
    uint64_t start, end;
    char c;
    start = rdtsc();
    func();
    end = rdtsc();
    printf("%ld ticks\n", end - start);
}

void flushFuncCache()
{
    // Assuming function to be not greater than 320 bytes.
    char* fPtr = (char*)func;
    clflush(fPtr);
    clflush(fPtr+64);
    clflush(fPtr+128);
    clflush(fPtr+192);
    clflush(fPtr+256);
}

int main(int ac, char **av)
{
    test();
    printf("Function must be cached by now!\n");
    test();
    flushFuncCache();
    printf("Function flushed from cache.\n");
    test();
    printf("Function must be cached again by now!\n");
    test();

    return 0;
}
```

Here, i am trying to flush the instruction cache to remove the code for 'func', and then expecting a performance overhead on the next call to func but my results don't agree to my expectations:

```
858 ticks
Function must be cached by now!
788 ticks
Function flushed from cache.
728 ticks
Function must be cached again by now!
710 ticks
```

I was expecting [CLFLUSH](http://x86.renejeschke.de/html/file_module_x86_id_30.html) to also flush the instruction cache, but apparently, it is not doing so. Can someone explain this behavior or suggest how to achieve the desired behavior.

Answer (score 9):

Your code does almost nothing in `func`, and the little you do gets inlined into `test`, and probably optimized out since you never use the return value.

gcc -O3 gives me -

```
0000000000400620 <test>:
  400620:       53                      push   %rbx
  400621:       0f a2                   cpuid
  400623:       0f 31                   rdtsc
  400625:       48 89 d7                mov    %rdx,%rdi
  400628:       48 89 c6                mov    %rax,%rsi
  40062b:       0f a2                   cpuid
  40062d:       0f 31                   rdtsc
  40062f:       5b                      pop    %rbx
  ...
```

So you're measuring time for the two moves that are very cheap HW-wise - your measurement is probably showing the latency of `cpuid` which is relatively expensive..

Worse, your `clflush` would actually flush `test` as well, this means you pay the re-fetch penalty when you next access it, which is out of the `rdtsc` pair so it's not measured. The measured code on the other hand, sequentially follows, so fetching `test` would probably also fetch the flushed code you measure, so it could actually be cached by the time you measure it.

Comment: okay, your explanation makes sense, How can I produce the desired behavior, that is move the function out of the instruction cache and measure the penalty? Will increasing the function size and using noinline attribute help?

Comment: @sud03r, probably not, a single function will miss once and then run ahead fetching the rest. Try defining multiple functions, if possible have each call the next.

Answer (score 2):

### it works well on my computer.

```
264 ticks
Function must be cached by now!
258 ticks
Function flushed from cache.
519 ticks
Function must be cached again by now!
240 ticks
```

Comment: Still I don't understand the reason behind the first output which is 264 ticks.