# gcc 5.3 not recognizing inline option

Tags: c, linux, performance, gcc

I am trying to run this code [clflush not flushing the instruction cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20600798/clflush-not-flushing-the-instruction-cache),

however I am getting following error with **gcc-5.3 version.**

```
inline void clflush(volatile void *p)
{
    asm volatile ("clflush (%0)" :: "r"(p));
}


undefined reference to `clflush'
```

**To my surprise when I remove inline then error is not there.** This confirm that gcc-5.3 version has bug with inline option.

I have checked with other gcc version 4.8, 4.9 but in those versions this error doesn't occur.

**How can I resolve this problem, so that gcc-5.3 can work with inline option.**.

uname -a gives following output

```
Kernel : Linux kali 4.3.0-kali1-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.3.3-5kali4 (2016-01-13) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Any link or clue to solve this problem will be great help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Most likely it's not a bug, but an intentional change in behaviour. What happens when you use `-std=gnu11` with the older compilers? I expect the same error. That option is now the default. If this is indeed the problem, it's possible to slightly modify the code to work in that mode, and after confirmation from you, details on how and why should make for a good answer.

Comment: You'll need to read https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-5/porting_to.html , quick tip: use `static inline`

Comment: @hvd thanks for prompt reply. you are right. I am getting same error with -std=gnu11 option with older gcc versions.

Comment: @nos, thanks for the link and your solution also works for me.

Comment: For future readers, the problem here has nothing to do with the asm. It may look like it, but that's just because the function name and the asm string are the same.  Also, depending on just how/why you are doing the flush you might want to consider adding the "memory" clobber to this asm.  Flushing won't help (and could hurt) if values for the cache line are still 'cached' in registers at this point.